# How/when memory is assigned to global variables in C

Tags: c

I am aware of C memory layout and binary formation process.
I have a doubt/query regarding the phase when and who assigns address to global variables.

```
extern int dummy;  //Declared in some other file  
int * pTest = &dummy;
```

This code compiles well. Here *pTest* will have address of *dummy* only if address is assigned to it.
I want to know in which phase (compilation or linker) does *dummy* variable gets address?

Comment: Probably during loading when the loader does address fix-ups.

Answer (score 7):

The compiler says:

```
int *pTest = &<where is dummy?>;
```

The linker says:

```
int *pTest= &<dummy is here>;
```

The loader says:

```
int *pTest= <dummy is at 0x1234>;
```

This somewhat simplified explanation tries to convey the following:

- The compiler identifies that an external variable `dummy` is used
- The linker identifies where and in which module this variable resides
- But only once the executable program is placed in memory is the actual location of the variable known and the loader puts this actual address in all the places where `dummy` is used.

Comment: As per my knowledge, initial value of 'initialized global variable' is stored in data section of binary (executable file). Hence for above example, executable 'pTest' value and 'dummy' variable's address stored in data section of executable file before loader comes to picture.

Comment: @electrospark, that is true for variables whose value can be determined at compile time. The value of `pTest` cannot be determined at compile time and neither at link time. Example: `int test= 1234;` yes, this variable will be in the data segment.

Comment: "neither at link time" - I wonder how my embedded board works, as there is no loader involved at any stage. Said that: wiothout further information from OP, it can't be said how exactly the process is. On bare metal, the linker very well determines the addresses of all symbols.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite, correct. There are many remarks to be made with my text, which generally refers to an OS with a loader (linux, windows,...). It is for example possible to create an image that when loaded at a particular address specified in the image, does not need any fix-ups.

Answer (score 0):

the actual process is actually a bit different.

The compiler saves the information in the object file about the the assignment and the external object reference.

The linker depending on the actual hardware IS and implementation calculates the absolute address ( if the code will be placed at the fixed address - for example the embedded uC project) or same virtual and sets the entry in the relocation table (If the code is position independent) and the loaded is changing this virtuall address to the correct one during the program loading and start-up.